# Caliburn.Micro locking the main view

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog, caliburn.micro

I am currently launching a rather lengthy operation from my main view. While this operation continues, it should be impossible to press any button on the main View. Furthermore, the progress should be reported in another Window.
I could update every CanXXX Guard properties, but that would be tons of code.

I would like to use the ShowDialog Method of Caliburn.Micro, but this methods waits until the Window returns with a return value.
So how can I show a modal Window with Caliburn.Micro which does not wait for some dialog to return ?

Comment: Why is the waiting a problem? Make it close when the operation is done. A dialog is the easiest way to block the main window.

Comment: The Problem is, that the calling method has to do work after the Dialog has been opened. I could transfer this part into the Dialog, but that smells.

Comment: If it's a lengthy method it should be on a thread (bgw) anyway. Keep it in the VM.

Comment: Can you not just wrap the whole application window in a `ContentControl` - you can set `IsEnabled` on the content control to disable all child controls regardless of the bindings. You can just bind up `IsEnabled` if you want that level of control in the main VM then pass messages using the aggregator from any VM that wishes to lock or unlock the application UI. Popups won't be affected so any dialogs will still be interactive (unless they are in the visual tree of the main VMs view)

Comment: Carleh, your answer is very good! Can you please post it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this in the past...

In your main/shell view -

```
<ContentControl IsEnabled="{Binding UILocked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanInverter}}">
    <SomeOtherControls..... blah blah />
</ContentControl>
```

In the main/shell viewmodel -

```
public bool UILocked { get { // getter } set { // prop changed code/setter etc... } }
```

Upon setting `UILocked` to true the whole UI should be disabled. `ContentControl` will disable all child elements and `IsEnabled` bindings for its children will be ignored

You can ensure that the main view subscribes to the event aggregator too:

```
public class MainViewModel : IHandle<ChangeUIStateMessage>
{
    public bool UILocked { get { // getter } set { // prop changed code/setter etc... } }

    public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator aggregator)
    {
        aggregator.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public void Handle(ChangeUIStateMessage message)
    {
        UILocked = message.UILocked;
    }
}
```

The message class may be as simple as:

```
public class ChangeUIStateMessage
{
    public bool UILocked { get; private set; }

    public ChangeUIStateMessage(bool uiLocked)
    {
        UILocked = uiLocked;
    }
}
```

Then you can just fire this via the aggregator from any VM to lock/unlock the UI

```
aggregator.Publish(new ChangeUIStateMessage(true));
```

If needed you can also modify the handler so that a list of objects that have initiated a lock is maintained, ensuring the UI is locked until *all* workers have finished (in case multiple VMs kick off a lock/unlock operation simultaneously)

Edit: Forgot to add - if your popup controls are in a separate visual tree (as popups usually are) they will not be disabled which most of the time works to your advantage (interactive popups/locked app).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider the [BusyIndicator](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator&referringTitle=Home) provided with the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/).